# Creating a contour plot from three data columns

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mesh

I have two columns of input data, that I want as my x and y axis, and a third column of results data relating to the inputs.  I have 36 combinations of inputs and then 36 results

I want to achieve something like this plot

[image]

I have tried using a `cmap` but get told the z data is in 1D and needs to be 2D and don't understand how I get get around this issue
Also attached another method below

```
data = excel[['test','A_h','f_h','fore C_T','hind C_T','fore eff','hind eff','hind C_T ratio','hind eff ratio']]
    
x = data['A_h']
y = data['f_h']
z = data['hind C_T ratio']
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = z
    
plt.pcolor(x,y,z)
```

Comment: You need to interpolate your `z` values on your grid, see [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have arrays `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]` then `meshgrid` will will give you two arrays of 3x3 each: `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]` and `[[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]`. In your case, you seem to have this already taken care of, since you have 36 each of x, y, z, values. So `meshgrid` won't be necessary.

If your arrays are well defined (already in the 11122233 and 456456456 format above), then you can just reshape them:

```
x = np.reshape(data['A_h'], (6,6))
y = np.reshape(data['f_h'], (6,6))
z = np.reshape(data['hind C_T ratio'], (6,6))
plt.contourf(x, y, z)
```

You can see more help about [contourf](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) for details.

On the other hand, if your data are irregular (the 36 points do not form a grid), then you will have to use griddata as @obchardon suggested above.